# Trigger autocomplete for the field of the modal that is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The scenario here is that on the several pages I am having modals that have a autocomplete search field. so instead of giving several different IDs to each field, and then triggering them, I used a common class and tried to trigger `autocomplete()` on the field that resides in modal with `.activeModal` class.

```js
function customerSearch() {
  $(".activeModal .customerSearch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".activeModal .customerSearch").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/operations.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          "req": "searchCustomer",
          "query": $(".activeModal .customerSearch").val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              id: item.id,
              label: item.label,
              value: item.value
            }
          }));
        }
      })
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(".activeModal .customerSearch").val(ui.item.label);
      $(".activeModal .customer_id").val(ui.item.value);
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  customerSearch();
});
```

However this is not working; it's not showing any results. Neither is it giving any errors when I checked the browser console.

What have I done wrong? I am new to jQueryUI so please spare me for silly mistakes.

EDIT : The question seems to be confusing many people, so; for example, here are 3 modals that have fields with same purpose on the same page:

```
<div class="modal" id="newGiftcard">
    <div class="head">
        <span class="modalTitle">
            Issue new giftcard
        </span>
        <span class="controller">
            <span class="close lnr lnr-cross"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <form id="newGiftCardForm">
            <input type="text" name="customer" placeholder="Search customer" class="ui-widget customerSearch" id="customerSearch" />
            <input type="hidden" class="customer_id" id="customer_id"/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="walkinGC" class="walkin" /><label for="walkinGC">&nbsp;&nbsp;Walk in</label>
            <input type="text" id="cardNumber" placeholder="Gift card number" />
            <input type="text" id="balance" placeholder="Balance" />
            <select id="payMethod">
                <option value="">Select a payment mode</option>
                <option value="cash">cash</option>
                <option value="card">card</option>
                <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="IssueGC">Issue</button>
            <button type="reset" class="grey">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="addBalance">
    <div class="head">
        <span class="modalTitle">
            add balance
        </span>
        <span class="controller">
            <span class="close lnr lnr-cross"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <p>please enter the amount:</p>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" id="card" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="amount" id="amount" />
            <select id="payMethod">
                <option value="">Select a payment mode</option>
                <option value="cash">cash</option>
                <option value="card">card</option>
                <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="addBal">Add balance</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="changeOwner">
    <div class="head">
        <span class="modalTitle">
            add balance
        </span>
        <span class="controller">
            <span class="close lnr lnr-cross"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <p>please enter the amount:</p>
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" id="card" />
            <input type="text" name="customer" placeholder="Search customer" class="ui-widget customerSearch"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="customer_id"/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="walkinGC" class="walkin" /><label for="walkinGC"> &nbsp; Walk in</label>
            <button type="button" id="changeOW">Add balance</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Rory McCrossan

Comment: As I see on document-ready you try to setup auto complete for this selector 
  $(".activeModal .customerSearch").autocomplete({, but at the moment of just-loaded page there is no activeModal as i can suspect. So just use .customerSearch selector

Comment: Agree with @AlexanderPoshtaruk to some degree. Also it may help to see the rest of the code and HTML.

Comment: I used it before asking this question, following are the problems with that: though 2-3 different fields have the same class, autocomplete works in only 1 modal of all those. 2. I want to perform these operations in the fields of only those modals that are active, because if 1 field in a modal has a value, the second field in another modal contains that value too! which if not changed after opening that modal, submits the previously assigned value! Sorry for a bit confusing reply though.

Comment: @sameermanek tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1jck94c4/3/ appears to be working (use Network tab to see POST request, that will 404 in the test)

Comment: Hi twisty, the problem is that I have more than one modals as I said earlier.. I know this works, but if you have more that 1 modals, the value in field of one modal will be reflected in the value in field of other modal. For the fiddle that you shared, where there is only one modal, using "id" is the best option